# How to boost speed cURL in php?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get followers form Facebook. So, I'm using cURL to get the json back. I wrote a little test but the test takes around 2 seconds as well as when I run locally. I want to increase its speed to the highest level, <s>please help me</s>, eg 1 second will CURL 5 threads url

```
function auto($url){
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $ch = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   return $ch;
   }
```

Comment: Do you think there's some form of speed option, or what kind of answer are you looking for? IS there any more context to this? Or did you do some request debugging (_VERBOSE) or network inspection?

Comment: Are you retrieving multiple urls? In that case, you might be able to use the `curl_multi_*` functions to handle them asynchronously. Otherwise, there's not a lot that PHP can do for you. A slow network request is the result of a slow remote server, network infrastructure issues (slow DNS lookups, for example) or a bad connection (with a lot of packet loss).

Comment: PD of [How do I measure request and response times at once using cURL?](//stackoverflow.com/q/18215389), [How to track down slow code in PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/22216953), [cURL really slow](//stackoverflow.com/q/1937188)

Comment: what makes you believe that it is cURL that is slow ? and not your net, fb, etc ...

Comment: enabling CURLOPT_ENCODING should make JSON transfers much faster